# Making a resume of activities on Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet where I need to create a resume of unfinished activities. Each employee have his own sheet just like below. The resume must contain the 4 activities with most % completed (but below 100%) and the name of the tasks.

To do the Status column I used the following formulas `=LARGE(IF(B:B<1;B:B);1)`, `=LARGE(IF(B:B<1;B:B);2)`, `=LARGE(IF(B:B<1;B:B);3)` and `=LARGE(IF(B:B<1;B:B);4)` and now I can't realize how to get the Task name corresponding to the percentage. I tried using `MATCH` funciton (Witch I called CorrespX) but it doesn't work. I also tried `INDEX` and `VLOOKUP` but I also couldn't make it. The target value is painted with green to help.

How can I get the Task name corresponding to the values? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the FILTER function?

Comment: @BigBen yes, it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using FILTER and SORT to return both the Task and Status:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:B7,B2:B7<1),2,-1),SEQUENCE(4),{1,2})
```

[image]

Change `,` to `;` as necessary.

In case there are fewer than 4 tasks with a status under 100%, you can wrap the formula in IFERROR:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:B7,B2:B7<1),2,-1),SEQUENCE(4),{1,2}),"")
```